# How to remove Lenovo's "ThinkVantage Fingerprint Software" logon icon?

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad, fingerprint

I think that the ThinkVantage Fingerprint software icon at the logon screen is annoying. I'm using Windows 7 Pro (64bit). It has a picture of a finger and it states "Swipe your finger" across the screen. It's funny and annoying at the same time. Does anyone know how to remove the icon while still having the functionality of the software?

Comment: I think I have to disappoint you and say this won't be possible without disabling the fingerprint recognition altogether...

Comment: +1 Ivo, that's what all of my hours have google-ing have nearly proved... I was just hoping that someone on here might have experience in doing this. :(

Comment: wierdly, windows 7 has built in fingerprint recognition, without the lenovo software - its worth trying removing it and seeing if windows 7 can handle it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows 7 supports the fingerprint scanner natively - you can remove the lenovo GINA that does the fingerprint scanning part of it, and log in using windows own native fingerprint log on option.

Comment: I never realised this, but I guess this would disable the integration with the `ThinkVantage Password Manager`, which I find very useful.

Comment: it may not - the password manager is a seperate application. I know windows 7 supports the fingerprint scanner cause i did a vanilla win7 install, so i didn't install the password manager.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in your ThinkVantage folder in

> C:\Program Files\ThinkVantage Fingerprint Software\rsc

… you can change replace the icon with a 256 x 256 png image.

Comment: Hmm... I may have to try this... I don't have a laptop with a fingerprint reader anymore, but I can get my hands on one. I will try this and accept if you are right. Thanks!

Comment: "I hate to be a necromancer": There's nothing wrong about this.  See http://superuser.com/badges/17/necromancer and http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2689/why-are-late-answers-allowed/2690#2690.

Answer (score 1):

I use the bioexcess fingerprint to log onto my desktop profile but disabled the fingerprint icon for web sites. I think I did this with a startup change but it could have been anything in msconfig. Now i want to turn it back on (the icon literally does not pop up on the left when I'm on a web page with log-in info) and i'm trying to figure out exactly how i turned it off. So it is possible. btw-My system is stable without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Update the Egistec Scanner Driver through the Device Manager, and instead of Bioexcess, I installed the Thinkvantage Fingerprint Software for Thinkpads.  It is much less intrusive, and takes much less resources.

Answer (score 0):

If your talking about the bioExcess Icon on the top left hand side of the logon screen I know how to get rid of that. Now the actual New User it makes that you can switch to, I am afraid I don't know how to remove it. As for the Icon, navigate to "C:\Program Files (x86)\EgisTec BioExcess\Layout\Images" and in that folder move these images to a different Folder of your choice, I wouldn't delete them just in-case you want to change back. The images are:
"icon_logon_128" "icon_logon_128_1" "icon_logon_128_2" "icon_logon_128_3" "icon_logon_128_4" and "icon_logon_128_5". Also move/get rid of, these Icons: "Tipicon1" "Tipicon2" "Tipicon3" "Tipicon4" "Tipicon10" and "Tipicon11". Welp that should do it, Hope this works for you ^^)

Comment: Great answer, but the problem is that I do not use "EgisTec BioExcess". I used "ThinkVantage Fingerprint Software." If I were using the other program I'm sure it would have worked though! Thanks a lot!. (I did search for that directory and could not find it just to double check)

Comment: Oh man sorry for the mix up of programs. I have a lenovo Laptop that can do the same thing with fingerprint logon, and I was tired of looking at it too so I searched through the files to find out how to get rid of it. I wish I could have been more help.